# how to limit django admin inline formsets

Tags: django, django-admin, inline-formset

How do you limit the inline formset in django admin?

Problem:

I have a table A with 1 to n relationship with B. Table A should have at least one Table B item and a max of 5 Table B items.

Answer (score 50):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options

Specify `max_num` in your `Inline` definition to limit the number.

`extra` specifies how many blank inlines to show.

Is the 1 inline required? As in you want to trigger a validation error if table B isn't filled with at least 1 row?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to disable the add button.

Comment: The add button is hidden by default if the total number of forms shown crosses the max_num specified.
So if your max_num is 5 , and you want to disable the add button specify extra = 5
Else whenever total forms reaches 5, add button will be hidden

Answer (score 0):

The enabling / disabling of the add button in an inline is managed through the `_has_add_permission` method

you could add to your inline class:

```
def _has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
   # add/remove possibility to add a line to an inline
    if obj.table_b_items.count() < 5:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```